# Bootstrap examples not showing correctly

Tags: html

I copied and tried this code for card groups https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/card/#card-groups and it is now showing correctly on my side.

Also, I used this CDNs (for CSS & JS(
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/

and got this weird looking result. Anyone has an idea what I'm doing wrong? Thank you

[image]

Comment: Check your browser console for errors and update the question please. Remember to open the developer tools (F12 on most browsers) and then reload the website.

Answer (score 0):

The examples you have are not examples of complete webpages.

You need to:

- include the Bootstrap boilerplate (css, js, container elements)
- replace the ... placeholders with real URLs

Comment: HI Quentin. Placeholders are not a problem (I'm aware of that) but the overall view is completely different (check URL that I posted (cards are not visible, not in one row etc.). I put CSS and additional three URLs (java etc.) that bootstrap required.

Comment: @AutomXer — https://imgur.com/4Tfy2SG — I can't reproduce the problem. You probably have made a mistake setting up the boilerplate.